# MSBuild CustomBuild AdditionalInputs from file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to set AdditionalInputs for a CustomBuild target, but from the content of a generated file (there is 1 such file per src file).

```
<Target Name="Custom" Condition="'@(CustomSources)' != ''">
    <ItemGroup>
        <CustomItem>
            <Command>
                ...
            </Command>
        </CustomItem>
        <AdditionalInputs>
            // contents from generated file
        </AdditionalInputs>
    </ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuild Sources="@(CustomSources)"/>
</Target>
```

I tried using the ReadLinesFromFile task to get the file contents, but was not able to store and pass the contents to the AdditionalInputs. Is there another way to accomplish this?

The intent here is to only re-run **Command** if any of the files listed in **AdditionalInputs** changed. This works when manually entering the filenames, but these need to come from a generated file.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do, what the function of CustomItem is or why you want to assign AdditionalInputs but then do not use it; can you clarify the example, make it minimal and eplxain what you expect? And if you use the typcial example code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/readlinesfromfile-task?view=vs-2019 i.e. uses ReadLinesFromFile and have `ItemName="AdditionalInputs"` doesn't that do what you need?

Comment: Seems like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What you were trying to do in first place?